# Number of lines of length 3 that can be placed in a X by Y grid

Tags: math, combinatorics

Given a grid of dimensions length X by height Y, how do I find the number of lines of length 3 that can be placed in the grid? Accounting for horizontal, vertical and diagonal lines.

EXAMPLE
3x3 grid - 3 horizontal lines, 3 vertical lines, 2 diagonal lines = 8 possible lines.
3x4 grid - 4 horizontal lines, 6 vertical lines, 4 diagonal lines = 14 possible lines.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that `X` and `Y` are both at least 3.

In every row, there are `X - 2` possible left-end points for a horizontal line of length three (all except the rightmost two columns). So the overall number of possible horizontal lines is `Y * (X - 2)`.

By symmetry, the overall number of possible vertical lines is `X * (Y - 2)`.

There are two types of diagonals according to their orientation. Consider those that are in upper-left to lower-right direction. Similar to the argument above, for the upper-left endpoint of any such diagonal of length three, there are `X - 2` possible columns and `Y - 2` possible rows. So the overall number of such diagonals is `(X - 2) * (Y - 2)`.

By symmetry, the overall number of the other type of diagonal is the same.

So the overall number of lines of length three is `Y * (X - 2) + X * (Y - 2) + 2 * (X - 2) * (Y - 2)`, which can be simplified to:

```
(2 * X - 3) * (2 * Y - 3) - 1
```

As expected, this formula does agree with your examples.